# Find value within cell from a series in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of addresses, such as this:

- Lake Havasu,  Lake Havasu City,  Arizona.
- St. Johns River,  Palatka,  Florida.
- Tennessee River,  Knoxville,  Tennessee.

I would like to extract the State from these addresses and then have a column showing the abbreviated State name (AZ, FL, TN etc.).

I have a table that has the States with their abbreviation and once I extract the State, doing a simple INDEX MATCH to get the abbreviation is easy. I don't want to use text-to-columns because this file will constantly have values added to it and it would be much easier to just have a formula that does the extraction for me.

The ways I've tried to approach this that have failed so far are:

1. Some kind of SEARCH() function that looks at the full State list and tries to find a value that exists in the cell
2. A MID or RIGHT approach to only capture the last section but I can't work out how to have FIND only look for the second ", "
3. A version of INDEX MATCH but that fails because I can't find a good way to search or find the values as per approach (1)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is it ***always*** the 3rd comma-separated element? If not, what are the exceptions. Is there really a period following the state's name? What's your Excel version?

Comment: Yes, all addresses follow the same structure "[place], [place], [state]." I'm using 2016

Comment: The strings you posted include _no-break spaces_ (ascii code 160).  Is this true of your data in Excel?

Comment: I noticed this too :)  It's a down arrow with Wingdings 3 (maybe copy and paste issue from source)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this formula, where A2 is the original text.

```
=FILTERXML("<data><a>" & SUBSTITUTE(A2,", ","</a><a>") & "</a></data>","data/a[3]")
```

An alternative would be to look for the 2nd comma as shown below. Note that the "50" in the formula is an irrelevant number required by the MID() function. It shouldn't be smaller than the number of characters you need to return, however.

`Char(160)` is a character that wouldn't (shouldn't) naturally occur in your text, as it might if the text comes from a UNIX database. You can replace it with another one that fits the description.

```
=TRIM(MID(A2, FIND(CHAR(160),SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",CHAR(160),2)) + 1,50))
```

The following variation of the above would remove the final period. It will fail if there is anything following the period, such as an unwanted blank. That could be accommodated within the formula as well but it would be easier to treat the original data, if that is an option for you.

```
=TRIM(MID(LEFT(A2, LEN(A2)-1), FIND(CHAR(160),SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",CHAR(160),2)) + 1,50))
```

To find the abbreviation I would recommend to use VLOOKUP rather than INDEX/MATCH.

Comment: That formula isn't available on Mac or Excel for web. Sorry, I should have specified I'm on a Mac

Comment: The second solution worked! Thanks very much. What's the best way to remove the "." from the end?

Comment: Thanks, Variatus. Appreciate your help.

Comment: You have two viable solutions now. For the benefit of future visitors, please mark the one you implement as "Selected".

Comment: More complex than required in my view. The 50 fails for strings longer than 50; the entire result returns a #Value! if there is no Char(160).  If you consider rectifying these two issues, I will review and consider upvoting.  ta

Comment: @James I don't know about more convoluted but your solution is shorter, which is why I like it. However, there are no states with names longer than 50 characters, and that makes my formula less convoluted at that point. On your other argument, Char(160) will be there because my formula puts it there. Not my invention, BTW, but standard practice. OP assured us that there would be 2 commas, and neither solution will work if there aren't. So, I'll have to forego your upvote this time but thanks for the offer.

Comment: @Variatus FWIW I was working on an answer very similar to your second formula when you updated your answer.  I found that the OPs sample data actually includes a couple of no-break spaces (ascii 160), which I guess has driven some of the commentary around those characters.   Since the OP says it works for them I'll assume the 160's aren't present in the real data.

Comment: @chris neilsen That makes me very glad early in the morning. Normally, it seems to me, you are the one beating me to the punch :-) I did copy the texts from OP's question though, and wonder why the Char(160) didn't show up in my trials. FWIW, as you say.

Answer (score -1):

Use this (screenshot refers):

```
=MID(MID(B3,1,LEN(B3)-1),SEARCH(",",B3,SEARCH(",",B3,1)+1)+3,LEN(B3))
```

[image: Excel screenshot for reference]

Comment: I like your approach but failed to upvote for two reasons. First, `SEARCH(",",B3,SEARCH(",",B3,1)+1)+3` must fail if there is no or more than one space following the comma. That is an unnecessary risk you could easily avoid using TRIM. Second `LEN(B3)` is a number that is larger than the length of the name of any state. Being extracted by a function gives the appearance of precision that isn't given. Considering both the better transparency and length of the formula, I would opt for a hard number. If you correct these two flaws I will upvote your solution.

Comment: thank you for letting me know, however, I have several challenges to you views: A) reasonable to assume (given sample data) that you've copied from a table with consistent formatting.  B) (most importantly) - if my solution fails it's likely the one you accepted would too for the self-same reason (e.g. if no 3 character gaps then char(165) would be missing and "find(char(165)...." in the soln you favoured would return #Value! (mine would at least return a partial name, in fact, it's not only shorter, but more robust (can still complete lookup with partial state name).

Comment: C) precision re a fixed number of 50 is not an excuse for downvoting or failing to vote - if anything, it's less precise (if formatting is so erratic/inconsistent as you would have me believe, then what do you think happens when 50 additional characters are unexpectedly present in the string?  I'd never use a fixed number and len() hasn't failed me for over 20 years now, I'm not about to change what has stood the test of time friend, esp. not for something far less robust.